# Which kernel is LTS for Ubuntu 18.04 and how to install it?

Tags: nvidia, kernel, ubuntu-drivers

I had issues with Nvidia 8600m and kernel 5 and I want to go to a stable setup.

Which kernel is LTS and works with Ubuntu 18.04 and where do I download it from?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (both 18.04 LTS & 18.04.1 LTS install media) came with the 4.15 kernel, with the option to use the HWE kernel when it came out.  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS ISO's or prior installations (with HWE kernel option enabled) use the 18.10, 19.04, 19.10 and 20.04 kernels so which kernel depends on whether or not you have HWE enabled (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support)   Ubuntu 18.04.2 (and later, eg. 18.04.3 is released this thursday) have HWE enabled by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (installed via Ubuntu 18.04 LTS or Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS ISOs/media) came with the 4.15 kernel, with the option to use the HWE kernel when it came out.

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed with 18.04.2 or later ISOs/media (or prior installations with HWE kernel option enabled) use the 18.10, 19.04, 19.10 and 20.04 kernels so which kernel depends on whether or not you have HWE enabled.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support

For more detail on HWE (hardware enablement stack) kernels please see

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

You can download kernels from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/  (both patches & deb's) though you'll already have the kernels installed; so I'd stick to default kernels (with/without HWE) to ensure they get patched automatically, but assuming you want to download for testing or other, you'll find them here.

Answer (score 1):

Even without considering manually installed kernels, a Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system can be in one of three kernel "families":

- General Availability: The metapackage installed is `linux-generic` or `linux-lowlatency`.  As of this writing, the kernel version is 4.15.0-55-generic for the first option.
- HWE: The metapackage installed is `linux-generic-hwe-18.04` or `linux-lowlatency-hwe-18.04`.  As of this writing the kernel version is 5.0.0-23-generic for the first option.
- Edge: The metapackage installed is `linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge` or `linux-lowlatency-hwe-18.04-edge`. I don't know anything about this "family" having no experience with it.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Comment: I think I'll go for 4.15 version. I currently have the HWE one and have issues with Nvidia. Weirdly I just got a notification to upgrade to 5.2.